# Testing a specific solution in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I have defined some constraints in my `.als` file, but when I click *Execute*, no solution is found. I have a specific solution in mind that I suspect "should" work, but evidently fails for some obscure reason that only Alloy can spot.

What I would like is to manually input my proposed solution into the Alloy Visualiser, and then ask Alloy to tell me which constraints are violated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is run Unsat Core to highlight the inconsistency. Then you might weaken the model by moving constraints from facts into predicates; you can then evaluate predicates and functions directly in the evaluator. Note also that the Alloy Analyzer recognizes formulas that construct instances and optimizes them eg, those in the form

```
r = a -> b + c -> d
```

Alloy doesn't let you just enter an instance and evaluate it, however.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Alloy optimising instance-constructing formulas -- that's very good to know.